# WCF and IIS confusion on the wsdl location

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, iis-7, hosting

I created my WCF project and it works fine when I just run it from the debugger.

But when I publish it to IIS and point a browser to the svc the path used has localhost in it.  Like this:

```
htpp://localhost/MyService/MyServices.svc
```

but the path that the webpage says to go to for the WSDL uses my computer name, like this:

```
http://MyComputerName.MyDomain.net/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl
```

When I click on the link it times out.  (Also, trying to view the services like that in WCFTestClient times out.)

However, if I go the wsdl using localhost then it works right away:

```
http://lcoalhost/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl
```

Any link that uses my computer name times out ("takes too long to respond").

Any idea on how to make my WCF service work with the computer name?

(NOTE: I am using Visual Studio Ultimate and IIS 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding MyComputerName.MyDomain.net to your proxy bypass list in Internet Explorer proxy configuration setting. Check that the IIS website has this FQDN in it's hostname in the site bindings.

Also what happens if you only use MyComputerName without the domain ?

Comment: It still times out with just MyComputerName (ie no domain).  I am afraid that I am very inexperienced with IIS (that part is usually done by my systems people.  But I did not want to bother them with this simple service).  I don't know what FQDN is or how to set it.  I will dig for how to set the proxy stuff and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: To add to the weirdness, I tried the full computer and domain url on a different computer and it brought up the wsdl just fine.  Shouldn't it be easier to get to from my computer than from another?

Comment: The issue was that my system folks had hard coded my DNS and WINS entries.  In troubleshooting I found that I could not even ping my computer.  Once I took out those hard codings it all worked again.

Comment: Gald to help you. But I suggest you learn the basics of IIS at least how to build a website or host a webservice. As a developer this understanding is essential even if your systems people will actually do the installation or configuration.